Azure Devops pipeline failing due to AZ.Accounts Module update by MSFT
I had this pipeline configured and working before today. However based on recent update to the module, I now get this error

Write-Error: This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.19.0. An earlier version of
Az.Accounts is imported in the current PowerShell session. Please open a new
session before importing this module. This error could indicate that multiple
incompatible versions of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets are installed on your
system. Please see https://aka.ms/azps-version-error for troubleshooting
information.

I tried adding this in my module script to remove the existing one and install with the new version 2.19.0. But no luck
$desiredVersion = "2.19.0"
$installedModule = Get-InstalledModule -Name "Az.Accounts" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Output "$($installedModule)"
if ($installedModule) {
    if ($installedModule.Version.ToString() -ne $desiredVersion) {
        Uninstall-Module -Name "Az.Accounts" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Install-Module -Name "Az.Accounts" -RequiredVersion $desiredVersion -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery
    }
} else {
    Install-Module -Name "Az.Accounts" -RequiredVersion $desiredVersion -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery
}
Import-Module Az.Accounts


You can try to add a PowerShell task before the Azure PowerShell task to install the module Az.Accounts 2.19.0. See below example as reference.
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Install Module Az.Accounts'
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.19.0 -Repository PSGallery -Force'
    
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'Check Module Az.Accounts'
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        azureSubscription: 'myArmConnection'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: 'Get-InstalledModule -Name "Az.Accounts"'
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'


